# Radial stack issue

Tags: layout, d3.js, radial

I'm trying to draw a radial chart (radar chart) using the Stack layout and Nest (as advised by mbostock). Code is here: http://bl.ocks.org/3017677 Purpose is to draw stacked areas along three axes of metrics (axis 1, 2 and 3). Areas map to min, average and max values along those metrics. Max area encompasses the average area which encompasses the min one.

The computations seem really fine until the path data string is built. That is, when entering for the layers, d.values looks OK while area(d.values) returns a somewhat correct motions sequence but microscopic values (e-14).

Didn't understand what I'm doing wrong yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the angle scale's domain. WIP at http://bl.ocks.org/3017677 for the curious minds.